# How to animate a webpage (HTML/JS) without losing scalability?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, interactive

I'm trying to make my webpage more interactive by making a small town-like map, with different buildings that are clickable and lead to different pages on my site, but I'm having a lot of difficulty animating the webpage with just HTML/JS and also making it stay the same even after resizing the window.

This is my test site right now, for clarity: https://people.ucsc.edu/~anlin/test#
(I am currently just switching between a png of the map and a gif of the buildings moving when the mouse is hovering)

How can I accomplish this, and should I be using something other than plain html/js to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Read this: https://www.sitepoint.com/dynamic-geo-maps-svg-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `<svg>` , which is a "scalable vector graphic"

Here is almost an exact example of what you described

[image]

https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ltpmv

Answer (score 1):

Probably `svg` would help you out. You can do awesome interactive stuff with svg. Meanwhile, you can also use `css` to create great animations. It really depends on what you need.

Check this out: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-svg-on-web-c5932dadca03

Some examples:
https://codepen.io/search/pens/?q=svg%20animations&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false